# When should I contribute to my IRA over my 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, roth-401k

I know there are a few different factors to this, such as if you've reached the contribution limit for the year on your 401(k). With a 401(k) you can get employer contribution matching and a higher contribution limit.

So other than reaching the contribution limit on your 401(k), when would you want to contribute to an IRA over a 401(k)? Does traditional versus Roth accounts make a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- you have already deposited up to the employer match on the 401(k) and the IRA is more attractive. (Features listed in other bullet points)
- the 401(k) does not offer the Roth version, and you prefer that as an option so you use Roth IRA
- you already have $100K+ in the 401(k), so the loan option is already optimized (i.e. the $50K limit is available)
- you like the strategy of converting to Roth over time.
- The 401(k) fees are high. After the match, it's just extra cost
- The 401(k) investing options are not varied enough or to your liking. IRA has far more flexibility
- (more to come)

Comment: How do you judge the "attractiveness" of an IRA or 401k?

Comment: Could you please explain the optimization of the 401k loan option?

Comment: The ability to borrow is limited to 50% of the 401(k) balance with a $50k borrowing cap. If I ignored the loan feature, some members would point out my oversight.